# Convert SQL SELECT statement to SSIS Data Flow Task

Tags: ssis

in the context of a traditional ETL I wrote several views (SQL SELECTs with some JOINs) that I would like to "translate" into Data Flow Tasks in SSIS.
Is there any tool to automate this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Either you C/P your logic. Or you choose your view as a Source. Or you develop it in BIML

Comment: An SSIS Dataflow uses a SELECT statement to read data from a source and inserts it into a target table. You'll probably still use the same query. What changes is *lookups*. *Some* of those joins are only meant to look up reference data. You can add Lookup transformations in your data flow. There's no way to *guess* which joins are lookups and which are necessary to produce the correct data though

Comment: For example, if one of the joins looks up product or country data, you could remove it and add a lookup transformation that caches all products and countries and adds the relevant info to each row that passes. A JOIN that matches invoices with line items though is definitely not a lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing SQL views into Data Flows in SSIS is generally a very bad idea. The SQL Engine is very good at fetching your data in the optimal way (on most cases) so you have the data as fast as possible. It uses indexes statistics, cache'd data and so on.

Obtaining the same result in a Data Flow will require to fetch the data from different tables and then do filtering and joining. Even if the SSIS is fast, it will always be faster to solve the query directly on the database (as long as it involves just 1 server) since they were build specifically for that purpose. It will be also a lot harder to design and to mantain (SSIS graphical interface Vs. SQL).

You should try to use SSIS just for its purpose, **integrate** data, and leave the heavy processing to your databases.

As for your question about automation, I don't think there is a tool to translate SQL views into DTS components, you will have to design them manually.

Comment: By far and away the correct answer here.  Do as little data processing in SSIS as possible.  Put it in your database and let the database engine do the heavy lifting it was designed to do.